# creating a matrix from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a file like this

- 1 2 3 4 5
- 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5
- 10 9 8 7 6
- 5 4 3 2 1

and i want the program to create something like this

- 1 0.1 10 5
- 2 0.2 9 4
- 3 0.3 8 3
- 4 0.4 7 2
- 5 0.5 6 1

  any help is appreciated I'm a beginner at python

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, like the order you would want this in? or the reason why a number belongs in a certain spot?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply with `zip` and list comprehension:

```
>>>l = [[1,2,3,4,5],[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5],[10,9,8,7,6],[5,4,3,2,1]]
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(*l)]
[[1, 0.1, 10, 5], [2, 0.2, 9, 4], [3, 0.3, 8, 3], [4, 0.4, 7, 2], [5, 0.5, 6, 1]]
```

Here, on every iteration of the list comprehension, x with have the zipped value of items from the sublists of `l` with the same index but transposed vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
your_file = open("your_file.txt", 'r')

matrix_one = [line.strip().split(" ") for line in your_file]

matrix_two = [list(x) for x in zip(*matrix_one)]

for line in matrix_two:
    print(" ".join(line))

your_file.close()
```